# Where is "session sufficient pam_lsass.so" and the "/usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/50-unity-greeter.conf"

Tags: 14.04, server, samba, lightdm, active-directory

I am new in Ubuntu, Ubuntu Server 14.04 LTS.

I am setting up a Samba File Server and join it to our domain.

I configured some of the configuration, but in the step 6 of this [guide](http://community.spiceworks.com/how_to/show/80336-join-ubuntu-14-04lts-to-a-windows-domain-using-pbis-open), I was unable to find the `session sufficient pam_lsass.so` in the `/etc/pam.d/common-session` and when seeing the `/usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/50-unity-greeter.conf`, it does not exist.

Kind guide me in this matter. Thanks in advance and will greatly appreciate any help.

Comment: The second file is for Desktop versions of Ubuntu.

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply. The `50-unity-greeter.conf`file? so, does this required if the computer I am joining to the domain is Server Version?

Comment: I would say it isn't required, since it controls the login screen for Desktop versions. Server editions usually use the TTY for that.

Comment: Ok, thank you for that information, how about the first file, I don't see the `session sufficient pam_lsass.so` but instead, the `session optional pam_lsass.so`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [`man pam.conf`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/pam.conf), `sufficient` and `optional` have longer equivalents:

```
sufficient
   [success=done new_authtok_reqd=done default=ignore]

optional
   [success=ok new_authtok_reqd=ok default=ignore]
```

The guide changes `sufficient` to  `[success=ok default=ignore]`, which is close to `optional`, so I think what it really wants to achieve is change `sufficient` to `optional`. Since the current configuration already uses `optional`, there's nothing for you to do in this step. If you would like to follow the guide exactly, simply change `optional` to `[success=ok default=ignore]`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @muru, so, no action required in the step, since the current config is `optional` and its equivalent is  `[success=ok default=ignore]`, right?

Comment: @Markmeplease yes, I think no action is required.